# C# SIMD Sort/Median using System.Numerics.Vector

Tags: c#, simd

I have a video processing code that needs to determine the value of each pixel by using the median of its 4 neighbor pixels. So, I have an array of 4 bytes and must find its median in a performance-effective way. First I must sort the array, then do the average of the 2 middle values. I have to do that for half the pixels of the image so it can be done in parallel.

Can this be done using System.Numerics.Vector?

Also this isn't clear in the docs: does System.Numerics.Vector create SIMD for x86 code or only x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I'm not going to bother with getting the data in the right places, just the median business.

I assume you have separate vectors for left/top/right/bottom. Having them packed together in a vector would be extremely annoying, and actually harder to set up too because that cannot be done with a simple load.

You don't have to sort (which would require a lot of comparisons and ConditionalSelects) to find the median of 4. It is enough to find the minimum and maximum and remove those (once each, of course). Finding the minimum and maximum is easy, just apply `Vector.Min` and `Vector.Max` a couple of times. "Removing" means subtracting them from the sum of the 4 things. Of course since the result of that represents the sum of two bytes, it cannot fit in a byte itself[<sup>note 1</sup>], so unfortunately most of the computation has be done in 16bit, halving the throughput. In the end, just shift the sum of the two middle values right by 1 to get their average, which you can convert back to 8bit.

Or in short, the median-of-4 is, without sorting:

```
median = (a + b + c + d - min(a, b, c, d) - max(a, b, c, d)) >> 1;
```

Optionally you can add 1 before the shift to get a rounded-up average.

1: if it wasn't for that, letting the calculations wrap would have solved everything. If it was median-of-3, the result *would* fit in 8 bits, so it could be done without widening (even though the sum may wrap, the subtractions would "unwrap" it by the same amount). Of course it could also be done with XOR then, for which it is more obvious that it works.

Comment: Great! Btw do you know if Vectors generate SIMD in x86?

Comment: @EtienneCharland as far as I know it's only enabled for x64

Comment: That kind of makes it pointless; hopefully they'll expand that in the future

Comment: @EtienneCharland it's not that bad, practically every system is x64, the only issue is that 32 bit code is required sometimes to use certain libraries

Comment: A lot of code is still restricted to x86; where I want to use it, x64 got recently released but is still experimental while 96% of people still use x86. It has to work for both.

Comment: I think for a x64 you can be sure that there's at least SSE 2.something. On x86, you might have nothing of the sort because the platform is so old. IMHO that's why they decided to do SIMD just on x64.